# Entity references same entity Symfony 3.3

Tags: php, symfony, twig, entity

(i'm french, sorry if I make mistakes). 
Hello, I'm trying to link my entity (called "Evenement") to itself, because 0 to X evenement can be linked to an evenement. 
I have one form to add a new evenement (it's working fine) and on the same page, I want to have another form to link evenement that I choosing to the current event. 
So in EvenementType, I have two builder (i don't know if it's a good solution, so I commented the second builder and I made EvenementAssocieType.php with this builder).

But when I check an evenement (a checkbox is used to link an evenement to another), nothing append and in the profiler, my submitted form doesn't appear.

You can find my code here : https://openclassrooms.com/forum/sujet/symfony-evenements-lies-a-un-evenement

Thanks for your help !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to make a self referencing many to many relationship in your entity. Here is an example found on [doctrine website](http://docs.doctrine-project.org/en/latest/reference/association-mapping.html#many-to-many-self-referencing), that you can adapt to your code:

```
<?php
/** @Entity */
class User
{
    // ...

    /**
     * Many Users have Many Users.
     * @ManyToMany(targetEntity="User", mappedBy="myFriends")
     */
    private $friendsWithMe;

    /**
     * Many Users have many Users.
     * @ManyToMany(targetEntity="User", inversedBy="friendsWithMe")
     * @JoinTable(name="friends",
     *      joinColumns={@JoinColumn(name="user_id", referencedColumnName="id")},
     *      inverseJoinColumns={@JoinColumn(name="friend_user_id", referencedColumnName="id")}
     *      )
     */
    private $myFriends;

    public function __construct() {
        $this->friendsWithMe = new \Doctrine\Common\Collections\ArrayCollection();
        $this->myFriends = new \Doctrine\Common\Collections\ArrayCollection();
    }

    // ...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for your answer, but something wrong in my code, but I don't know what it is...

```html
/**
 * ORM\@ManyToMany(targetEntity="KeolisBundle\Entity\Evenement", mappedBy="myEvents")
 * @ORM\JoinColumn(nullable=true)
 */
private $evenements;

/**
 * ORM\@ManyToMany(targetEntity="KeolisBundle\Entity\Evenement", inversedBy="evenements", cascade={"persist"})
 * ORM\@JoinTable(name="evenement_evenement",
 *      joinColumns={@JoinColumn(name="evenement_id", referencedColumnName="id")},
 *      inverseJoinColumns={@JoinColumn(name="event_assoc_id", referencedColumnName="id")}
 *      )
 */
private $myEvents;
```

When I generate my Entities, there's no changing (I have myEvents in my constructor). And when I dump the SQL query, i have a message "nothing up to date"

Comment: It's working, I forgot to change 1 thing in my form !